# Layout in Flutter: row containing a square and 3 lines of text

Tags: flutter, layout

I want to create the following layout:
[image]

It's a **Container**, containing a **Row**, children:

1. a square **Container**, unknown height or width
2. a **Column**, children: 3 **Text** widgets (width is unknown)

The size of the square **Container** should be the height of the parent **Container** (its width = its height). the **Column** with the 3 **Text** widgets should expand to the rest of the parent **Container**.

Is it possible in Flutter? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom widget:

```dart
class BoxWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  BoxWidget(/*...*/);
  
  Widget build(_) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(widget.text1, style: style),
            Text(widget.text2, style: style),
            Text(widget.text3, style: style),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to have a SingleChildScrollView for he 3 Text lines parent. I'd like to see if it's possible for that container to get the height of those 3 lines...

Comment: SingleChildScrollView is not required. You can remove it if you want to. I just add it around certain widgets to prevent overflow errors.

Comment: this results in a "RenderBox was not laid out" error - and it makes sense, since Flutter doesn't know how to layout it...

Comment: Well, wrapping the Row with IntrinsicHeight solved this issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, first create a container then it’s child should be a row, then the children of the row should be another container which will act as the square, and then the column which will have 3 text widget as its children. Also I will advice you to wrap the container acting as the square and the column in expanded widgets both separately in the expanded widget wrapping the column set the flex to 3 and for the container expanded widget set flex to 2.

Comment: wrapping the sqaure and the column in flex (2 an 3) sets the width of the sqaure, meaning it won't be exactly a sqaure...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible. The trick here is to use `LayoutBuilder` which returns the size that parents can allow. Here, I used `maxHeight` as height and as well as the width of *Red Square Container* and Column takes rest of the width.

```dart
Container(
  width: 500, //parent size
  height: 100, //parent size
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, size) {
      return Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: size.maxHeight,
            width: size.maxHeight
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ); 
    }),
  ),
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to set the parent container height (to 100 in your example), since the 3 lines of Text won't fit there probably... I'd like to see if it's possible for that container to get the height of those 3 lines...

Comment: I include 100 just for example.  I get what you mean. So Height of the parent should be 3 * height of the Text. Is that right?

Comment: correct. Looks like IntrinsicHeight solves it. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on "The Anonymous Koder"'s answer, this is the way to do it:

```
return IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'line 1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            Text(
              'line 2 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            Text(
              'line 3',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```